# Asp.Net Core 3 graceful shutdown throws OperationCanceledException

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to gracefully terminate a ASP.Net Core 3.1 service (which will run in Kubernetes). When Kubernetes stops a service, it will send a SIGTERM event to the application, at which point I want in-flight requests to complete (which may take several seconds) before terminating... I think I can catch this in a hostedservice, as below, and hence not stop immediately.

The following works, but with a timeout of 5 seconds or longer, I receive an OperationCanceledException. Could anyone shed any light on why I get an OperationCanceledException or how shed any light on an alternative way to delay a SIGTERM event, to allow a graceful shutdown?

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLogBuilder
            .ConfigureNLog("nlog.config")
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>(); })
                .Build()
                .Run();

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal(e, "Stopping due to exception");

            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

This is the hosted service...

```
    internal class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

        public LifetimeEventsHostedService(
            ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> logger,
            IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
            _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
            _appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void OnStarted()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("OnStarted has been called.");

            // Perform post-startup activities here
        }

        private void OnStopping()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("OnStopping has been called.");
            // Perform on-stopping activities here


            // This works, but a timeout of 5 seconds or more subsequently causes an OperationCanceledException
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        private void OnStopped()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("OnStopped has been called.");

            // Perform post-stopped activities here
        }
    }
```

Comment: The cancellation token is the one that deals with the operation cancelled exception. Probably if you are doing something that takes longer than the shutdown, the cancellation token will throw that exception.

Comment: The SIGTERM default timeout is 5 seconds so if you try and wait any longer, boom, operation timeout exception.

Comment: How on earth do you change that then?

Comment: Not to familiar on how to change it kubernetes but I wouldn't change it there. You could try an implement a queue for storing jobs in case of shutdown for example.

Comment: I can set the `shutdown timeout` as per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#shutdown-timeout) but setting it to a high value (eg 30 seconds) doesn't prevent my OperationCanceledException.

Comment: I would suggest that waiting for the outstanding tasks to finish is the wrong idea in the first place.  You have been asked to quit, and therefore should do that as quick as possible, which means cancelling any outstanding requests, close open files, tidy up and shut down.

Comment: @Neil - Thanks for the opinion, the question was specifically around a graceful shutdown scenario in Kubernetes, where you want to stop receiving new requests (new requests will be directed to another instance of the application) and then shutdown after in flight requests complete. From [go](https://blog.golang.org/go1.8) "allowing servers to minimize downtime by shutting down only after serving all requests that are in flight" - I'm trying to achieve the same here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm open to alternative approaches to graceful shutdown with ASP.Net Core 3.1, as it stands, I'm using a hosted service.

Within the .Net Core app, I was setting [ShutdownTimeout on the webhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1), however, setting the [ShutdownTimeout on the generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1), does allow me to gracefully wait a number of seconds (more than the default sigterm, which is 5 seconds) prior to shutdown. The hint from @PmanAce helped me work that out.

As such, the following codes allow me to gracefully terminate. One caveat, the Thread.Sleep in LifetimeEventsHostedService must be less than `option.ShutdownTimeout`.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
                services.Configure<HostOptions>(option =>
                {
                    option.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                });
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

The following LifetimeEventsHostedService

```cs
public class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

    public LifetimeEventsHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStopped()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnStopped");
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnStopping");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        Console.WriteLine("Sleep finished");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    private void OnStarted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnStarted");
    }
}
```