# Failed to gracefully shutdown application (IIS Hang)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, migration, asp.net-core-webapi, application-pool

on application pool my .net core(3.1) application suddenly shutdown(in production server), I often get the following entry in event log Failed to gracefully shutdown application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SITEName'.

Comment: In most cases you need other evidence to tell that there is a serious issue. Such are typical warnings on many machines.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you find this application is not gracefully shutdown?  Do you write some trace logs in your application to trace the gracefully shutdown. If not, I suggest you could try to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252562/7609093) to do it.

Comment: It's usually seen in event viewer/Application.  Event Id 1005, source "IIS AspNetCore Module V2"