# How to run code before the ASP.NET Core 5.0 kestrel server shuts down? Used to work in 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In .NET Core 3.1, I had the code below, and everything worked fine. However, in .NET 5.0, I think the stopping order has changed, so only the OnStarted function is properly called, not OnStopping and OnStopped. Any ideas how to fix it? No other code has changed in my project, I just changed back to 3.1, reverted a few "init;" back to "set;" and everything works as it should.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
```

---

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NLog;

namespace xlwteam1.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All this just to set the SystemIsShuttingDown boolean to true to prevent new websocket connections
    /// and trigger a save, flush etc of all data in memory.
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228641/asp-net-core-3-graceful-shutdown-throws-operationcanceledexception
    /// </summary>
    public class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

        /// <summary>
        /// The logger
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public LifetimeEventsHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
        {
            _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Log.Info("Registering OnStarting...");
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void OnStopped()
        {
            Log.Info("OnStopped");
        }

        private void OnStopping()
        {
            Log.Info("OnPrepareForStopping");
            // in order to make the time the system doesn't accept new connections as short as possible
            // let us do some work even before we block new connections. 
            Program.PrepareForStopping(Log).Wait();
            Log.Info("OnStopping");
            Startup.SystemIsShuttingDown = true;
            Program.ToDoBeforeShutdown(Log).Wait();
            Log.Info("OnStopping finished");
        }

        private void OnStarted()
        {
            Log.Info("OnStarted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do everything on `StopAsync`? You are calling asynchronous methods synchronously instead of using the asynchronous method you already need to implement

Comment: Does your code rely on this example? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ihostapplicationlifetime?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want to do as much shutdown work as possible before I stop servicing requests, so OnStopping is the most important part. That means that a restart of my service is a downtime of less than 10s, i.e. is not noticable.

Comment: @Jehof Yes, that is my code, so I think this is a bug in net5.0.

Comment: are you sure the service is started normally (`StartAsync` is called)? There might be some change in the design making the application lifetime callbacks not working. Your final shot is putting the code in the `StopAsync`, although it's not always ensured to be called but it should work almost the time.

Comment: Hi @mattias, When you register the  OnStarted, OnStopping and OnStopped methods, they should be in the ExampleHostedService constructor method, try to modify your code as below: `public LifetimeEventsHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime){ _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime; _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted); _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping); _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);}`

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv, I will try that, but that is not how it is done at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ihostapplicationlifetime